# Excel: Conditional Formatting to colour Row based on two cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Lets say I have a 4 x 5 table (below). Is there a way I can say if `Date1` or `Date2` `> 30` days old (`=today()-30`) then colour these 4 cells dark blue.

```
Fruit   Date 1      Date 2      Price
A       08/01/2020  05/01/2020  50
B       29/11/2019  24/12/2019  60
C       19/11/2019  09/11/2019  55
D       31/12/2019  29/12/2019  65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formula in conditional formatting:

```
=($B2+30<TODAY())+($C2+30<TODAY())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Onq quick question, which option did you select after making a new rule?

Comment: Did you mean which rule type? Then - 'Use a formula...'